# Link between items from database and onclick

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

my app using cordova3.4, 
I display list of users from database lets say user1, user2  and user3
I want, if click on user1 then display user1 info.
if click on user2 then display user2 info.
if click on user3 then display user3 info.

I have for loop which display the three users, how to link between onClick event and user Id.

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){        
var userId = results.rows.item(i).user_id;

var div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.setAttribute('class', 'left');
var a1 = document.createElement("a");
a1.setAttribute('onClick', "showUserProfile(userId)");
....
....
}
}

function showUserProfile(userId)
{
alert("user Id: " +userId);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey why you using create div using javascript here , just use jquery

```
    var html="";
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){        
    var userId = results.rows.item(i).user_id;

    html+="<div class='left' onclick='showUserProfile("+userId+")'></div>"


    }
    $("#id").append(html);//  where you append this element
```

now you write function

```
function showUserProfile(userId)
{
alert("user Id: " +userId);
}
```

[ref](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Not everyone has the capability of using jQuery in their projects.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that `userId` is not actually being passed here:

```
a1.setAttribute('onClick', "showUserProfile(userId)");
```

You should instead revise this line similar to how the other answer shows, but here it is without jQuery add:

```
a1.setAttribute('onClick', "showUserProfile(" + userId + ")");
```